# MySQL query inside query

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm pretty new to MySQL, so this probably is an easy question for experienced people, but I just can't figure this out. 
I need to get items from database where user has posted a comment, and there is newer comment by someone else.

My table has these collumns

```
app_id - id of the item

app_comment - comment blank if rate is present

app_rate - rating blank if comment is present

date - date of posting

device_id - unique id to identify each user.
```

I have written simple query to get each comment the user(device_id) has posted on.

```
temp table:
SELECT `app_id` FROM `appaction` WHERE `device_id` = '00000000-5a24-5a06-0000-00005c907706' AND `app_comment` <> ''
```

But can't figure out what to do next. Now I somehow need to get only those app_id from main table where somebody else(different device_id) has a newer post on each of these items

**Update:**
Data example: 
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8d986/1

Note: that this is just sample to get the idea how the table looks. In reality it has about 10 000 values inside.

for example: I'm giving out device_id to php script, and in the output I want all app_id where user has posted himself and there is newer comment after his.

**Input sample:**
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66258/1

**Desired output** is for input ffffffff-c565-9b4a-ffff-ffffc9d821fd

img/Honda/AccordPICS/4167946157_a5b77093bc_b.jpg

because there is newer post for this app_id by somebody else.

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired output?

Comment: also, if possible, provide them here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: I added sample to get the idea how table looks like. I'll try to provide sample data and desired output for that table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly then app_id is a link to another table and not the id for appaction. In that case you can do something like:

```
SELECT ua.id AS user_item_id, oa.id AS other_item_id FROM appaction ua
INNER JOIN appaction oa ON (ua.app_id = oa.app_id AND oa.app_comment <> '' AND oa.date > ua.date)
WHERE 
    ua.device_id = '00000000-5a24-5a06-0000-00005c907706' 
    AND oa.device_id != '00000000-5a24-5a06-0000-00005c907706' 
    AND ua.app_comment <> ''
```

This gets the items for a device that have an item for the same app_id posted after the item. `other_item_id` is the id of the later action.

Edit: To get the output you need just change the above query to:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(ua.app_id) FROM appaction ua
INNER JOIN appaction oa ON (ua.app_id = oa.app_id AND oa.app_comment <> '' AND oa.date > ua.date)
WHERE 
    ua.device_id = 'ffffffff-c565-9b4a-ffff-ffffc9d821fd' 
    AND ua.app_comment <> ''
```

Comment: I added table example, to get a better understanding of a problem

Comment: Worked just as expected.. I'll take my time and try to figure out this query to understand it. Thank your for your help !

Comment: @Datenshi No problem, let me know if I can explain the query better.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are looking for all those apps whose latest post is from other than device id 00000000-5a24-5a06-0000-00005c907706. If that is true, try the below query

```
SELECT `app_id`, group_concat(device_id) as device_ids FROM `appaction` 
GROUP BY app_id ORDER BY date DESC 
HAVING SUBSTRING_INDEX(device_ids,",",1)!= '00000000-5a24-5a06-0000-00005c907706'
```

Comment: I'm looking for those app_id who has a post by "device_id" and there is a newer post by different device_id for the same app_id tried executing this query but it gets sql syntax error.